# Extracting multiple strings using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm new to RegEx and I find it really confusing, so I would like a simple example of how to extract multiple strings of the same type.

Let's say we have a random string and I want to capture anything that is surrounded by "###". So I assume the pattern would look something like this:

```
string str = "dsad###hi###vdkv324da###dog###fs";
Regex pattern = new Regex("###.+###");
```

How do I match and store more than one occurrences? And the bigger question - after I do that I'll be left with "###hi###" and "###dog###", so how do I extract the "hi" and "dog" from those?

Comment: First of all, you must define your requirement. When you say _anything that is surrounded by "###"_ that's not unambiguous. For instance, in your sample string, the whole `hi###vdkv324da###dog` part lies between two `###`s. So what is your solution to that? Are you using two adjacent `###` an opening and closing parts?

Comment: There is a nice tool to test regular expressions: https://regex101.com/ Although, keep in mind that .NET C# regexes are a little specific, so some tokens may not work.

Comment: Regex isn't always the best method to use.  In this case a string() method will work : string[] split = str.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution:

`#{3}([^#]+)#{3}`

```
#{3}      // 3 number signs, then
([^#]+)   // 1 or more characters excluding a number sign (captured as group), then
#{3}      // 3 number signs
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aUwEiJ/1)

Comment: Ah I noticed my mistake now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, along with how to extract string parts. Uses a version of your own original `Regex`, and grabs the strings between adjacent `###`.

```
string str = "dsad###hi###vdkv324da###dog###fs###d###";
Regex pattern = new Regex("###.+?###");

List<string> matched = new List<string>();
foreach(Match mat in pattern.Matches(str))
{
    string val = mat.Value;
    int start = val.IndexOf("###") + 3;
    int len = val.LastIndexOf("###") - start;
    matched.Add(val.Substring(start, len));
}
```

**Update: More concise extraction of string:**

```
foreach(Match mat in pattern.Matches(str))
{
    matched.Add(mat.Value.Trim('#'));
}
```

Comment: `string val = mat.Value.Trim('#');` is more laconic.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Indeed it is! Why didn't I think of that. Updating the answer. Thanks.